Are the categories of $3$-dimensional smooth and topological manifolds equivalent?
Someone told me that for $n = 1, 2$ and $3$ the category of $n$-dimensional smooth manifolds is equivalent to the category of $n$-dimensional topological manifolds. This was an extreme shock to hear. And I think they were wrong. I already know that every $n$-dimensional topological manifold has an unique smooth structure for those $n$. But are the corresponding categories equivalent? I have no idea how to try to find an invariant that distinguishes them. I'm also curious about the $C^k$ and PL categories.

I doubt that this is true. Certainly the forgetful functor does not induce an equivalence, since it's not full (there are continuous, non-smooth morphisms; similar argument goes for the $C^k$ categories). This doesn't rule out that there could be some weird equivalence.

This is indeed true. The topological, piecewise-linear, and smooth categories are all equivalent in three dimensions. A reference is given at wikipedia.

@DietrichBurde I believe that reference is only saying that every topological manifold in dimension 3 has unique PL and smooth structures. This is much weaker than the corresponding categories being equivalent.

To disprove this statement in dimension $1$ I suggest to first find a categorical characterization of the real line, which makes sure that it is preserved by the equivalence. Then try to argue that also the internal ring structure is unique in some sense. Then derive an isomorphism of rings between $C(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. And this doesn't exist for algebraic reasons. (Rough plan!)
